# trying to understand macro definition

Tags: c++, macros

I found fragments of a very odd code:

```
//first fragment 
bool status = fileToImage (name, size, stride, data);

//second fragment
WRAPABLE_HND (8, ScreenInterface, bool, fileToImage, CompString &, CompSize &, int &, void *&);


third fragment
#define WRAPABLE_HND(num,itype,rtype, func, ...)    \
rtype func (__VA_ARGS__);               \
void  func ## SetEnabled (itype *obj, bool enabled) \
{                           \
   functionSetEnabled (obj, num, enabled);      \
}                           \
unsigned int func ## GetCurrentIndex ()     \
{                           \
   return mCurrFunction[num];           \
}                           \
void func ## SetCurrentIndex (unsigned int index)   \
{                           \
   mCurrFunction[num] = index;          \
}
```

Could you explain me how does above macro definition work ?

Comment: Blergh, that's very much C. In C++ you really don't have to do things like that.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz, not quite true. In C++ you may still need to do things like this, it's just that people will mock you for it.

Comment: Would I sound too snarky if I explained how it works in one word: "poorly"?

Comment: Looks like an attempt at code obfuscation to me.

Comment: When you're trying to figure something like this out, a good first step is to run it through the preprocessor and look at what you get back. For example, if you're using `gcc` you can specify the `-E` switch to preprocess without compiling, so you can look at the post-preprocessed code.

Comment: Clear case for using templates? Any reason why one would use Macros over templates for such cases. C++ template gives advantage of scoping and less obfuscation

Comment: I think your example has spaces incorrectly around the `##`.

Comment: @crashmstr Whitespace around `##` is ignored

Comment: Eclipse CDT unrolls the macros nicely. That might help in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a macro for defining a set of related functions. It declares/defines these functions:

- Declares a function named `func` (4th macro parameter) returning `rtype` (3rd macro parameter), whose parameter types are specified by the 5th and successive macro parameters.
- Defines a function named `funcSetEnabled` (where `func` is substituted by the macro argument) which takes a pointer to `itype` (2nd macro parameter) and a boolean, and forwards them to a function named `functionSetEnabled()`, along with one more argument `num` (1st macro parameter).
- Defines a function named `funcGetCurrentIndex` (`func` substituted again) which returns the `num`-th element of an array named `mCurrFunction`.
- Defines a function named `funcSetCurrentIndex` (`func` substituted again) which takes an index and writes it into the `num`-th element of the array named `mCurrFunction`.

In other words, it's a bit like a preprocessor-based template.

In your example, the macro is "called" with arguments `8, ScreenInterface, bool, fileToImage, CompString &, CompSize &, int &, void *&`. So it will produce the following functions:

```
bool fileToImage(CompString &, CompSize &, int &, void *&);

void fileToImageSetEnabled(ScreenInterface *obj, bool enabled)
{
  functionSetEnabled(obj, 8, enabled);
}

unsigned int fileToImageGetCurrentIndex()
{
  return mCurrFunction[8];
}

void fileToImageSetCurrentIndex(unsigned int index)
{
  mCurrFunction[8] = index;
}
```

So apparently, it's something like a property-generation system: generating the prototype of a function and several helpers doing something with it.

Comment: Just some helping hints to OP: ## is Macro Concatenation. It evaluate the left side with the preprocess, evaluate the right side with the preprocessor, and then smoosh the two together, and is how they are making those bonus function names. The "..." argument makes the macro varadic, __VA_ARGS__ represents the extra augments, so that's how define the function footprint. As for the "why would you do such a thing": Normally you see this kindof pattern when trying to get static polymorphism without templates, but mCurrFunction looks like dynamic to me...either way C++ has better ways to do this.